# Is there a bug in AWS .Net SDK for getting count of running EC2 instances?

Tags: .net, sdk, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Hi have 1 EC2 instance that is stopped. (Ubuntu Rails App Server (ami-e49e758d)) But when I run a sample from that comes with SDK, it shows me running instance as 1.  Whom should I trust. What I see on AWS Console or sdk sample output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, 'Running' instances as reported by the API means 'Existing' - this is telling you how many instances are actually present (i.e. being 'run' by the Xen hipervisor). You can then interrogate each instance item to determine its' specific activity status (i.e. Stopped, Running, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I got the actual state of that instance with **InstanceState** Property. ec2Response.DescribeInstancesResult.Reservation[0].RunningInstance[0].InstanceState.Name

Comment: so how does Amazon bill people? On the RunningInstance or the actual state of that instance (InstanceState)?

Comment: Instance usage billing is generated from CPU usage, so you are not billed for instances sitting in the 'Stopped' state (the VM is actually discarded, but the boot volume remains intact and ready to be used to reconstitute the VM at Restart). Note that you do still continue to pay for that volume storage, though - as well as incurring the cost of having an unattached ElasticIP if one was assigned before you stopped the instance.

Comment: oh gosh! that's too complicated. I'm experimenting with micro-instance, though. Could please point me to document/link which will describe all these gotchas. Thanks buddy!